# Query (update set "in")

Tags: database, oracle

Can you help me with this problem? an update is necessary but the error
appears in Oracle. I need to replace the OLD quantities with NEW

```
Select Results:
PRODUCT   OLD   NEW
12345837          1      0
15198683          2      1
```

Query Update:

```
UPDATE
       (SELECT 
      T2.PRODUCT,
      T1.RESERVED_AMT AS OLD,
      T1.RESERVED_AMT-T2.RESERVED AS NEW
      FROM PRODUCT_LOCATION T1
      INNER JOIN Temp_Reservado_Control2 T2
      ON T1.LOCATION_ID=T2.LOCATIONE AND T1.PRODUCT_ID=T2.PRODUCT AND T1.RESERVED_AMT > 0) t
      SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

> SQL Error [1779] [42000]: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps
>   to a non key-preserved table

thank you very much for the help and for your suggestions.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it with `UPDATE` and repeated subquery in `SET` and `EXISTS` clause.

Also, You can use `MERGE` for it.

-- Using Update and exists

```
UPDATE PRODUCT_LOCATION T1
SET T1.RESERVED_AMT = T1.RESERVED_AMT - 
(SELECT T2.RESERVED 
FROM Temp_Reservado_Control2 T2
WHERE T1.LOCATION_ID=T2.LOCATIONE AND T1.PRODUCT_ID=T2.PRODUCT AND T1.RESERVED_AMT > 0)
WHERE
EXISTS
(SELECT 1
FROM Temp_Reservado_Control2 T12
ON T1.LOCATION_ID=T12.LOCATIONE AND T1.PRODUCT_ID=T12.PRODUCT AND T1.RESERVED_AMT > 0);
```

-- Using MERGE

```
MERGE INTO PRODUCT_LOCATION T1
USING (SELECT T2.RESERVED, T2.LOCATIONE, T2.PRODUCT 
FROM Temp_Reservado_Control2 T2) T2
ON ( T1.LOCATION_ID=T2.LOCATIONE AND T1.PRODUCT_ID=T2.PRODUCT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T1.RESERVED_AMT = T1.RESERVED_AMT - T2.RESERVED
WHERE T1.RESERVED_AMT > 0;
```

**Note**: If there are more than one matching record in `Temp_Reservado_Control2` then you will need to use aggregate function on `RESERVED` column.

Cheers!!